# How to dynamically add new data to a 2D Array?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, hashtable, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to implement a simple hash table using chaining collision handling.
**main.c:**

```
int main ()
{
    const int size = 20;
    const int key = 30;
    const int data = 40;

    htable ht;
    htable_init(&ht, size);
    htable_insert(&ht, key, data);
    htable_insert(&ht, key+1, 22);
    htable_insert(&ht, key+2, 23);
    htable_insert(&ht, key+2, 23);
    assert(htable_get(&ht, key) == data); // Expected: 40
    int d = htable_get(&ht, 415);
    assert(htable_delete(&ht, key) == data); // Expected: 40
    assert(htable_delete(&ht, key) == 0); // Expected: 0
    htable_destroy(&ht);

    // It is recommended to do further tests on your own

    return 0;
}
```

**htable.h:**

```
struct _ht_entry_ {
    int key;
    int data;
    struct _ht_entry_* next;
    struct _ht_entry_* prev;
};
typedef struct _ht_entry_ ht_entry;

struct _htable_ {
    ht_entry** entries;
    int size;
};
```

**htable.c:**

```
void htable_init(htable* ht, int initial_size)
{
    ht->entries = (ht_entry**) calloc(initial_size, sizeof(ht_entry*));
    if(ht->entries)
    {
        ht->size = initial_size;
    }
}

void htable_insert(htable* ht, int key, int data)
{
    ht_entry* newEntry = malloc(sizeof(ht_entry));
    if(!newEntry)
        return;

    newEntry->data = data;
    newEntry->key = key;
    newEntry->next = NULL;
    newEntry->prev = NULL;

    ht_entry** entries = ht->entries;
    *entries = newEntry;
    newEntry->data = 1;
    *(entries + 1) = newEntry;
    newEntry->data = 2;
    *(entries + 2) = newEntry;
    newEntry->data = 3;
    *(entries + 3) = newEntry;
    newEntry->data = 4;
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        ht_entry* entry = *(entries + i);
        printf("*(entries + %d) : %p\n",  i, *(entries + i) );
    }
}
```

In the example above I tried several ways to store the new entry in the `HashTable` but none of them worked.
I also don't understand why the addresses are identical.

**output:**

```
*(entries + 0) : data: 2  0x60003a410
*(entries + 1) : data: 2  0x60003a410
*(entries + 2) : data: 2  0x60003a410
```

I also tried `entries[0][0] = newEntry;` because I thought `ht_entry** entries;` is a `2D Array` but that didn't work either.

So how can I fill my `HashTable`?

Comment: Could you add main as well ?

Comment: I added now main.c

Comment: Detail: "ht_entry** entries; is a 2D Array" --> `entries` is not a 2D array, but a pointer to pointer to `ht_entry`.  It uses syntax like `ht_entry[x][y]`  like a 2D array.  `ht_entry  entries[4][5]` would be an example of a 2D array.

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between code and output.

Comment: Yeah thx i forgot to adapt it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at `htable_insert`. First you create a new entry on the heap and keep a pointer to it (named `newEntry`). Then you set your `key` and your `data`.

So far so good.

Now you dereference `entries` and set it's value to `newEntry`. Since `entries` is an array of pointers to pointers (2D is just a fancy name for this), dereferencing it gives you a pointer to `ht_entry`. What that means is that you don't copy the struct `newEntry` points to into the array, but you just save it's pointer. Then you proceed to do this 3 more times, each at the next greater index. In the end, entries is filled with 4 pointers to the same struct. Thus, when you print it's addresses, you get always the same address.

Comment: Thank you very much that explains everything.